# LiDAR data for 3D use

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar

What data type do I need to create a LiDAR 3D surface model?
I have downloaded LiDAR/DSM data from Environment Agency, both as a WMS and as individual ASCII files, and it looks good but I want to view this data in 3D rather than 2D. Similar to what a Scene has by default in ArcGIS Pro for the Ground Terrain 3D surface (image attached showing what mine looks like). Basically I want a 3D DSM.

[image: ArcGIS Pro scene]

I have done this sort of thing in the past with other software such as QGIS, and even perhaps ArcMap, but I am struggling in ArcGIS Pro but I don't think it is a GIS problem, I am not convinced I have the right data or I am going about it the right way! I am by no means an expert in 3D and LiDAR data, but I do want to use it and understand it more.

I firstly tried to download data from the Environment Agency, and this gives me ASCII files, but I think these are basically raster files (?) and I probably need some sort of vector dataset, with a XYZ so I can plot each height value by it's attribute?

I am sure in the past I got LiDAR data as a shapefile or some other vector format, but when I look on EA website, or the Defra website (I have an account), then it only gives me options for WMS and so on, which I don't think are any good if I want to make this data 3D.

I have been looking into this for a couple of days now and I thought I would ask how other people are doing it. I have watched some online guides and people have created a LAS dataset from LAS files, but I can only seem to get hold of ASCII files or Web Map Services.

Not sure if I just need to find somewhere to download the appropriate file types, or if I am over-complicating the whole thing!

Comment: Sorry I am trying to explain what I am wanting to do, which is create a 3D surface using LiDAR/DSM. I have Lidar/DSM data as an ASCII file but I can't seem to create a 3D surface from this, only 2D. I presume I need a point dataset with the height as an attribute.

Comment: Is your lidar classified?

Comment: This guide might help you https://orca.cf.ac.uk/85324/1/259.pdf

Comment: Thank you, will take a look at that. I did actually follow a similar guide before but ArcGIS Pro doesn't seem to have ASCII to raster tool. I do have access to ArcMap though so will look to do it in that.

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz, that pdf was really useful. It seemed I had to use ArcMap to do this as I had to convert the ASCII files to raster, I could then use these raster files as a surface in ArcGIS Pro. Thanks again